# jQuery .blur on input AND div classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form with multiple input fields. I'm using a blur function to trigger an AJAX request when ever an input field is clicked out of like so:

```
$(".innerItems input").blur(function() {
    $.ajax({
        // etc
    });
});
```

However, I've also built a custom "select menu" using DIVs and jQuery like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/tctc91/gWS2L/

How can I simulate a "blur" so that when the value changes in my custom select menu, the AJAX request is triggered like it normally would if it were an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger events on elements programatically by using `trigger()`:

```
$(".innerItems input").trigger("blur");
```

So in your code, it would be:

```
$(".currentMenu li").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".currentMenu").prev().html($(this).text());
    $(this).closest(".currentMenu").prev().append('<span class="dd-arrow"></span>');
    $(".innerItems input").trigger("blur");
});
```

Comment: ha, that's incredibly simple. I'll remember trigger() in the future now! Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that since using this method, when the blur is triggered, it seems to be sending several ajax requests at once? I'll do some exploring but in case I've missed something, I thought i'd post this here.

Comment: Solved it. It was triggering an AJAX request for each input within the innerItems div. I simply changed the blur to just one of the other input fields ID's and it now only performs one request.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a listener on the click event just add the ajax to the bottom of that ?

```
$(".currentMenu li").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".currentMenu").prev().html($(this).text());
    $(this).closest(".currentMenu").prev().append('<span class="dd-arrow"></span>');
    // ajax here
    doAjaxStuff();
});​

$(".innerItems input").blur(doAjaxStuff);

function doAjaxStuff() {
    $.ajax({
       // etc
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom event say `customMenuChanged` and trigger it whenever you change the value.

```
$(".currentMenu li").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $prev = $(this).closest(".currentMenu").prev();

    //Check if the value actually changed or same item is selected
    if($prev.text() != $(this).text()){
         $(document).trigger('customMenuChanged', $(this).text());
    }

    $prev.html($(this).text() + '<span class="dd-arrow"></span>');
});

$(document).bind('customMenuChanged', function(e, data){
     alert("Menu changed " + data);
     //Code here to make ajax request
});
```

You can bind event to any element you want and trigger it.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/gWS2L/6/